# Access denied occurs in visual studio installation process

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, installation

when I try to install Visual Studio Professional (2012, 2013, 2013 with SP2), an error occurs:
Setup engine (Access is denied).

Log file shows me this errors:

```
[0520:1D30][2014-08-04T09:55:40]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 3470762  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 3470762
[0520:1D30][2014-08-04T09:55:40]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:RemoveExistingProducts Restart:None
[0520:1D30][2014-08-04T09:55:40]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[0520:1D30][2014-08-04T09:55:40]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[0520:1D30][2014-08-04T09:55:40]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
[22D0:22D4][2014-08-04T09:55:40]i325: Registering dependency: {02a877fe-5dac-4ac0-b869-4b9da00f651c} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_amd64,v12, package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64
[22D0:22D4][2014-08-04T09:55:40]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to register the dependency on package dependency provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_amd64,v12
[22D0:22D4][2014-08-04T09:55:40]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to register the dependency on the package provider.
[22D0:22D4][2014-08-04T09:55:40]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to execute package dependency action.
[0520:1D30][2014-08-04T09:55:40]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to register the dependency on per-machine package.
[0520:1D30][2014-08-04T09:55:40]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to execute dependency action.
[22D0:22D4][2014-08-04T09:55:40]w331: Could not remove dependency: {02a877fe-5dac-4ac0-b869-4b9da00f651c} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_amd64,v12, package vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, error: 0x80070005
[22D0:22FC][2014-08-04T09:55:40]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab41974C84E43AEE700F28BA7B03AF3FF7 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab41974C84E43AEE700F28BA7B03AF3FF7, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{9347889B-C22A-3905-901F-C05D8F73C929}v12.0.21005\packages\BuildTools_MSBuildResMsi_x86\BuildTools_Res1.cab.
[0520:0BBC][2014-08-04T09:55:40]i000: MUX:  Source confirmed
```

I have stopped my antivirus for installation time, run installation as administrator and I followed this page:

> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872457/pl

I have windows 7 with SP1 (x64), .net framework 4.5.1.

Comment: Please post solution if this problem is resolved. I'm also encountering same issue.

Comment: My solution wasn't cool. I reinstalled my windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

just stop your antivirus and try again. this solved my problem

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that works on Windows 7.

You have to open Windows registry (<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then `regedit`). Find keys that start with `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Dependencies`.

When you click on them you should get `Access denied error`. You have to change permissions on them. You can do that following those steps:

1. Right-click on the problem key
2. Select `Permissions...`
3. Add yourself to Group or user names (fill the `Enter the object names to select (examples)` field by clicking on `Advanced` then `Find now` and click on your user name)
4. give yourself *Full Control > Allow*
5. click `Advanced`
6. Choose `Owner` tab
7. Change `Owner` to yourself, check the box *Replace owner on subcontainers and objects...*, and click OK
8. Ignore the `Access denied error` message
9. Click OK twice
10. Voila, you have full access

If you do this for every key, you will be able to install VS.

[I found this solution here.](http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/questions/registry-error-opening-key-cant-delete-it/)

Comment: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Dependencies
I clicked right and gave permissions that.
It solved my problem

Comment: This solution was useful and helped me to install VS2013! Also this was useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1lhIN4rY1M

Answer (score 1):

Same issues trying to install VS 2015 and VS 2017 on a Win 10 box. Unfortunately None of the above worked for me. Main problem was access issues to "C:\Program Files\dotnet\swidtag", the swidtag directory was completely inaccessible even from the local admin account - ownership was unknown and couldn't be changed.

I noticed that when I booted in safe mode that dir disappeared. On a whim, I removed the PC from the domain (changed to workgroup), logged on as Administrator and did a "Run As Admin" on the installer.

The swidtag directory was then accessible and .net core installation completed successfully.

I still had problems with installing the various VC runtimes (2017, 2015, 2013). I had to install them manually, but before that would work I had to do a disk clean, including removing previous install points, then reboot for each runtime installer.

That finally allowed the rest of the VS installer to complete.

Answer (score 1):

MalwareBytes was blocking access, had to turn it off to get this working

Answer (score 0):

On a corporate machine I cannot disable the anti virus software.

Changing the Compatibility options for the `vs_community_ENU.exe` executable to `Run this program as an administrator` resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error today.

The message at the beginning of the log file was

```
error 0x5: Access is denied 
at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId, Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
...
```

In my case it was Microsoft Excel (Office 365) that was preventing access to the required folders or files.

It seems that not only anti-virus software can trigger this behaviour.